# Can I prevent endfloat from changing \leftmark and \rightmark?

Tags: sectioning, floats, header-footer, memoir, endfloat

I am working on a thesis with floats at the end of each chapter. `endfloat` lets me keep the figs/tables near their first callouts while writing so the order is correct, but I don't want to use the poorly-customizable sectioning `endfloat` provides. I circumvented it to some extent, but now my headers, configured with `memoir`, are messed up at the Floats and Tables sections.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here's a MWE showing my problem (headers go bad at page 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%  FLOATS AND TABLES  %%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[nolists,nomarkers,noheads,figuresfirst]{endfloat}
    \AtBeginTables{\section{Tables}\vfill}
    \AtBeginFigures{\section{Figures}\vfill}
    \AtBeginDelayedFloats{}
    \renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vfill\clearpage}
    \setfloatlocations{table}{p}
    \setfloatlocations{figure}{p}
%\usepackage{booktabs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%  FORMAT HEADERS  %%%%%%%%%%%%
\makepagestyle{endfloatTakeover}
\makeoddfoot{endfloatTakeover}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddhead{endfloatTakeover}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{endfloatTakeover}{\linewidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makepsmarks{endfloatTakeover}{%
\nouppercaseheads
\createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{. \ }
\createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{Chapter }{: \ }}
\pagestyle{endfloatTakeover}

%%%%%%%%%%%%  MWE TEXT  %%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\section{First Intro Section}
\lipsum[1] See~\fref{fig1}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
FIGURE 1
\caption{Vivamus vehicula dolor laoreet neque imperdiet consequat} \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Second Intro Section}
\lipsum[3]
 See~\fref{fig2}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE 2
\caption{Vivamus vehicula dolor laoreet neque imperdiet consequat} \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]
See~\tref{tab:tab1}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
    Morbi in turpis faucibus, sollicitudin sem eu, condimentum nibh. \\
    Quisque pharetra nunc volutpat purus venenatis, ut cursus purus consectetur. \\
    Fusce suscipit massa eu libero blandit, a facilisis risus pharetra. \\
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{ia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. }
    \label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

Comment: The example doesn't compile because `\end{figure}` must start at column 1.

Comment: that's odd, it compiles for me. I will edit it so other people can use it without errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package `endfloat` issues a `\markboth` command without any option for disabling it.

You can remove it with the following trick after loading `endfloat`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\efloat@process}{\markboth}{\@gobbletwo}{}{}
\makeatother
```

We change `\markboth` into `\@gobbletwo` which simply gobbles the two arguments originally for `\markboth`.

Here's the top of your page 3

[image]

### Update

With version 2.6 of the package, the patch is no longer necessary and the simple declaration

```
\renewcommand{\efloatheading}[1]{}
```

in the preamble will have the same effect.

Comment: Awesome. I will have to keep this in mind if there are other packages with problematic commands in them.

Comment: This patch does not work anymore with endfloat 2.6 (or newer). Here `\renewcommand\efloatheading[1]{}` is the way to go.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I've not yet seen version 2.6. But thanks for the update!

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I looked at version 2.6; you have `\uppercase` in the default definition for `\efloatheading`, but it should be `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: @egreg I just try to be as compatible to older versions as possible, and previous versions have used `\uppercase`, too.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt `\MakeUppercase` and `\uppercase` are equivalent when the latter doesn’t produce garbage.